# c# to geojson popup items bracketing []

Tags: c#, json, geojson

I have a database of GPS coordinates and information about trucks and I’m trying to build a map with that information using GeoJson. I collect the information using MYSQL and I’m creating the GeoJson file in c#. I can create the correct GeoJson file to show the location, heading and a small popup. However; I want to expand that popup. I’ll be using 1 truck in the examples for simplification. I also changed the coordinates for this example.

My C# output;

```
{
  "type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features":[
    {
      "type":"Feature",
      "properties":{
        "popup":{
          "title":"Truck_001",
          "subtitle":"Laatst geupdate: 23.1500 uur geleden.",
          "imageUrl":"<left blank for stacksocial>",
          "items":{
            "type":"text",
            "label":"text",
            "value":"text items"
          }
        },
        "tooltip":"Laatst geupdate: 23.1500 uur geleden.",
        "marker":{
          "prefix":"fa",
          "icon":"fa-chevron-up",
          "markerColor":"#003da5",
          "iconColor":"white",
          "square":false,
          "circle":false,
          "pureIcon":false,
          "layer":"layer1",
          "size":"medium"
        }
      },
      "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[
          1.981588,
          32.1926765
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The truck will show on the map, but the items will not be shown due to missing the following brackets: ‘[]’

The desired output (see ‘[‘ and ‘]’ around the item):

```
{
  "type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features":[
    {
      "type":"Feature",
      "properties":{
        "popup":{
          "title":"Truck_001",
          "subtitle":"Laatst geupdate: 23.1500 uur geleden.",
          "imageUrl":"<left blank for stacksocial>",
          "items":[ /*HERE*/
            {
              "type":"text",
              "label":"text",
              "value":"text items"
            }
          ] /* HERE */
        },
        "tooltip":"Laatst geupdate: 23.1500 uur geleden.",
        "marker":{
          "prefix":"fa",
          "icon":"fa-chevron-up",
          "markerColor":"#003da5",
          "iconColor":"white",
          "square":false,
          "circle":false,
          "pureIcon":false,
          "layer":"layer1",
          "size":"medium"
        }
      },
      "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[
          1.981588,
          32.1926765
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My C# Code:

```
public class Marker
{
    public string prefix;
    public string icon;
    public string markerColor;
    public string iconColor;
    public bool square;
    public bool circle;
    public bool pureIcon;
    public string layer;
    public string size;
}

public class Popup
{
    public string title;
    public string subtitle;
    public string imageUrl;
    public Items items;
}

public class Items
{
    public string type;
    public string label;
    public string value;
}

public class Properties
{
    public Popup popup;
    public string tooltip;
    public Marker marker;
}

public class Geometry
{
    public string type;
    public double[] coordinates;
}

public class Feature
{
    public string type;
    public Properties properties;
    public Geometry geometry;
}

public class GeoJSON
{
    public string type;
    public List<Feature> features;
}

public class SinglePosition
{
    public string headingicon;
    public string ts;
    public string Lastupdate;
    public string ticksts;
    public string ticksnow;
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
    public int heading;
    public string devId;
    public int heading1;
}

public static object[] Evaluate(object[] input)
{
    string dbres = input[0].ToString();

    var allPositions = dbres.FromJSON<SinglePosition[]>();
    if (allPositions == null || allPositions.Length == 0)
        return null;

    var toMap = new GeoJSON() { type = "FeatureCollection", features = new List<Feature>() };

    foreach (var p in allPositions)
    {
        if ((p.heading > 315) || (p.heading <= 45))
        {
            p.headingicon = "fa-chevron-up";
        }
        else if ((p.heading > 45) && (p.heading <= 135))
        {
            p.headingicon = "fa-chevron-right";
        }
        else if ((p.heading > 135) && (p.heading <= 225))
        {
            p.headingicon = "fa-chevron-down";
        }
        else if ((p.heading > 225) && (p.heading <= 315))
        {
            p.headingicon = "fa-chevron-left";
        }
        else
        {
            p.headingicon = "fa-car";
        }
        toMap.features.Add(new Feature()
        {
            type = "Feature",
            properties = new Properties()
            {
                popup = new Popup()
                {
                    title = p.devId,
                    subtitle = "Laatst geupdate: " + p.Lastupdate + " uur geleden.",
                    imageUrl = "<URL>",

                    items = new Items()
                    //[
                    {
                        type = "text",
                        label = "text",
                        value = "text items"
                    }
                    //]
                },
                tooltip = "Laatst geupdate: " + p.Lastupdate + " uur geleden.",
                marker = new Marker()
                {
                    prefix = "fa", // glyphicon or fa
                    icon = p.headingicon,
                    markerColor = "#003da5",
                    iconColor = "white",  // #b60055
                    square = false,
                    circle = false,
                    pureIcon = false,
                    layer = "layer1",
                    size = "medium"
                }
            },
            geometry = new Geometry()
            {
                type = "Point",
                coordinates = new double[] { p.lng, p.lat }
            }
        });
    }

    return new object[] { toMap.ToJSON() };
}
```

I have read online that those ‘[]’ brackets are attributes, but I have no idea how to use them. How could I use them in my code so that the class items uses them?

Comment: Change `public Items items;` to `public Items[] items;` in your `Popup`-Model.

Comment: @BoredomOverload Thank you for the reply. Changing that gave the following error: [126,37]Cannot implicitly convert type ‘Yodiwo.UserCode.CSharp.UserClass.Items’ to ‘Yodiwo.UserCode.CSharp.UserClass.Items[]’

Comment: @BoredomOverload Yes I did. And applying your suggestion gave that error. I'm not experienced enough and I don't know how to solve that error. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: If you copied my answer and the code you posted is the only snippet that uses `Popup.items` that error shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These brackets (`[]`) indicate an array, both in your JSON and in C#. You could just make `items` of the type `Items[]`, but that would limit you to a fixed size array, so i choose `List<Item>` for the Task.

This should work:

```
// ...

popup = new Popup
{
    title = p.devId,
    subtitle = "Laatst geupdate: " + p.Lastupdate + " uur geleden.",
    imageUrl = "<URL>",

    items = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item
        {
            type = "text",
            label = "text",
            value = "text items"
        }
    }
}

// ...

public class Popup
{
    public string title;
    public string subtitle;
    public string imageUrl;
    public List<Item> items;
}

public class Item
{
    public string type;
    public string label;
    public string value;
}

// ...
```

Comment: That should work... And it does! This solves the issue and I can continue improving the popup.

Thank you for the quick help

Comment: I wanted to test a bit more before marking it as answer.

The list works great and I can add multiple items. Great! I wish I had a higher reputation so I could upvote you.

Comment: Don't want to make a separate post for this, but I have a followup question. (hope you're still active and read this)  

Items are working and now I want to make a table. Table expects "value": [ ["Row1","Row1"],["Row2","Row2],["Row3","Etc"] ]  

How could I achieve this in c#? Should I make a new list<Table> tables ?   
 

The table would be a new item  
type = ""table",  
label = "Table",  
value = (see above)

Comment: @LaurensdeGraaff this should be a seperate question, since questions and answers don't really belong in the comments. Once you made your new question, feel free to ping me and i'll do my best to answer it :)